# decimal value not getting updated from the rails app but gets updated when changed from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite, bigdecimal

Okay, so I am not able to update decimal value through the rails app (model class) but if changed from rails console it works perfectly fine.I am not able to save the updated record in to database
this is my function def below

```
def self.currentprice_cal(id)
  totalstock = @stockname.stocksinmarket+@stockname.stocksinexchange
  @stockname.currentprice = @Buy_id.price.to_f*@Buy_id.numofstock.to_f
  @stockname.save
  #@stockname.update(currentprice: @stockname.currentprice.to_f)
  @update_currentprice_files = Stock.update_current_price(id,@stockname.currentprice)
end
```

this my model class

```
class CreateStocks < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :stocks do |t|
  t.string  :stockname
  t.decimal :currentprice, precision: 4, scale: 2  
  t.decimal :dayhigh, precision: 4, scale: 2
  t.decimal :daylow, precision: 4, scale: 2
  t.decimal :alltimehigh, precision: 4, scale: 2
  t.decimal :alltimelow, precision: 4, scale: 2
  t.integer :stocksinexchange
  t.integer :stocksinmarket
  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

in rails console it works fine

```
irb(main):015:0> u = Stock.first
Stock Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks"   ORDER BY "stocks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Stock id: 30677878, stockname: "Intel", currentprice: #        <BigDecimal:5fbdbf0,'0.4552E2',18(45)>, dayhigh: #<BigDecimal:5fbd790,'0.552E2',18(45)>, daylow:  #<BigDecimal:5fbd3d0,'0.2201E2',18(45)>, alltimehigh: #<BigDecimal:5fbd100,'0.457E2',18(45)>,  alltimelow: #<BigDecimal:5fbca70,'0.2209E2',18(45)>, stocksinexchange: 47, stocksinmarket: 3,  created_at: "2014-12-18 06:50:08", updated_at: "2014-12-19 06:04:18">
irb(main):016:0> u.currentprice
=> #<BigDecimal:5fbdbf0,'0.4552E2',18(45)>
irb(main):017:0> u.currentprice = 45.34  
=> 45.34
irb(main):018:0> u.save
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "stocks" SET "currentprice" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "stocks"."id" =  30677878  [["currentprice", 45.34], ["updated_at", "2014-12-19 07:18:34.214567"]]
(148.2ms) commit transaction
 => true
```

I dunno if I am doing something wrong here ,I am not able to figure it out

i am calling current price_cal from here

```
       @user_buying = User.find(@Buy_id.user_id)
       @user_buying.cash = @user_buying.cash - @Buy_id.price*@Buy_id.numofstock.to_f
       logger.info @Buy_id.user_id
       @user_buying.save
       #@user_selling = User.select('cash').where(:id => @Sell_id.user_id).first
       @user_selling = User.find(@Sell_id.user_id)
       @user_selling.cash = @user_selling.cash + @Sell_id.priceexpected*@Buy_id.numofstock.to_f
       @user_selling.save

       @stockused = StockUsed.create(:user_id => @Buy_id.user_id, :stock_id => @Buy_id.stock_id,:numofstock => @Buy_id.numofstock)
       @stockused = StockUsed.create(:user_id => @Sell_id.user_id, :stock_id => @Sell_id.stock_id,:numofstock => -@Buy_id.numofstock)

       @stockname = Stock.select('stockname,stocksinmarket,stocksinexchange,currentprice').where('id'=>id).first
       User.currentprice_cal(id)

       @notification = Notification.create(:user_id =>@Buy_id.user_id, :notification => "You bought #{@Buy_id.numofstock} stocks of #{@stockname.stockname} at the rate of $#{@Buy_id.price} per share", :seen => 1, :notice_type => 1)
       @notification = Notification.create(:user_id =>@Sell_id.user_id, :notification => "You sold #{@Buy_id.numofstock} stocks of #{@stockname.stockname} at the rate of $#{@Sell_id.priceexpected} per share", :seen => 1, :notice_type => 1)
```

Comment: Post the code where you call the `currentprice_cal` method.

Comment: you never use the `totalstock ` variable you set up? where do you set up `@stockname`? What sql is generated by calling the model method?

Comment: probably another [strong-parameters-induced confusion](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) ... please post controller code, as @roob asked

Comment: i am calling all the functions from user.rb model class

Comment: sorry for the late reply :p

Comment: all the functions and their function calls are from user.rb model class .... a the controller just calls a function from user.rb class and inturn calls the rest of the functions

Comment: the value of currentprice does change when i log it when the app runs ...its just that it doesnt get saved to the db

Comment: Instead of your model class's code, you've posted your migration's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless absolutely required, don't use instance variables in the class method that you've defined. There's a good chance that at least one of those instance variables isn't properly set when you call the method. Subsequently, your database row isn't updated.

Either pass the object and new value to the method as arguments, or pass the ID and values as arguments and fetch the object from the database within the method.

Comment: cant instant variables be called any where within the class ?

Comment: You're using a class method. And I don't know if you're defining the instance variable at the class level. If you're sure you're doing it right, then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: mmmm let me check i am able to access all the variables though only the save not working

Comment: looks like ur trick worked :) I passed id and fetch from db within the method itself.It got updated..thankssss